# intraweb delphi modalwindow

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I come by this post to seek your help, I use delphi 10.3 with intraweb 15 and especially the iwmodalwindow component, unfortunately the component does not refresh, it always displays the same file, the code is:
with iwmodalwindow do
reset;
src:='report.pdf';
show;
end

when I change the request I delete the file and create another one but I have the old file which comes back despite it being deleted

Comment: You claim that you Delete file. Where? On server or client side? Also bare in mind that with web pages you can define some elements to be stored in temporary internet folder. Those elements might not be downloaded again from the server on next page update but instead loaded from temporary internet files folder instead. This is usually done to reduce network traffic. It has been some time since I last worked with IntraWeb so I don't remember exactly how you control whether certain web elements can be store in temporary internet files or always downloaded from server.